# Parsing a string with time zone given as a string

Tags: python, datetime

I am comparing two timestamps parsing. One is:

```
datetime.datetime.strptime("2022-10-20 13:13:13 UTC", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z")
```

which returns `datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 20, 13, 13, 13)`.
Note that it neither fail (i.e. it parses the `UTC` part) nor add a time zone to the resulting object.
The second parsing is:

```
datetime.datetime.strptime("2022-10-20 13:13:13 +00:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z")
```

which returns `datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 20, 13, 13, 13, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)` with the correct time zone.

As far as I understand the technical note #6 [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#technical-detail), both should yield the same results.
I don't understand the difference, nor how the output of the 1st case is the expected one and aligns with the documentation. I would love to have an explanation on the first case. PS: I would like to avoid using `dateutil`.

EDIT: I'll try to focus my question. How can I parse the string `"2022-10-20 13:13:13 UTC"` and get a time zone aware `datetime` object?

Comment: Replace 'UTC' with 'Z', then parse with `'%z'` (lower-case z)?

Comment: @FObersteiner This is pretty much the 2nd case I mentioned. As no offset is specified in your suggestion the input is parsed as UTC. But it doesn't answer my question.

Comment: Concerning *technical note #6*, it doesn't say that the result will be aware. So to answer your question: `%Z` simply ***ignores*** specifiers such as 'UTC'. Imho, the docs could be more clear here, since naive datetime in Python means *local time* implicitly - Which can lead to unexpected results if you e.g. default = UTC (as it is in other languages).

Answer (score 1):

Using only the standard library, you cannot parse `UTC` directly, i.e. to get an aware datetime object. **`%Z` directive will simply make the parser ignore it**. However, you can replace it with `Z` (zulu time == UTC), which can be parsed with `%z` directive:

```py
from datetime import datetime

s = "2022-10-20 13:13:13 UTC"

dt = datetime.strptime(s.replace("UTC", "Z"), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z")

print(dt)
print(repr(dt))
# 2022-10-20 13:13:13+00:00
# datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 20, 13, 13, 13, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
```

Or, as I've described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62769371/10197418), use `fromisoformat` after you replace it with `+00:00`:

```py
dt = datetime.fromisoformat(s.replace("UTC", "+00:00"))

print(dt)
print(repr(dt))
# 2022-10-20 13:13:13+00:00
# datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 20, 13, 13, 13, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
```